# How to improve my collection performance?

Tags: mongodb

In my collection should I create one index for all my fields or an index for each fields in my document ?

My Collection :

```
 {
   "_id": ObjectId("53bfb3cd4109e65f728b4b53"),
   "id_client": NumberLong(8667554),
   "id_page": NumberLong(87664),
   "id_campagne": NumberLong(646545),
   "id_application": NumberLong(987987987987),
   "id_groupe": NumberLong(2),
   "year": NumberLong(2014),
   "month": NumberLong(7),
   "day": NumberLong(11),
   "hour": NumberLong(8),
   "uid": NumberLong(78658765),
   "is_new_fan": NumberLong(0),
   "creation_time": NumberLong(1405069193),
   "is_player": NumberLong(1),
   "total_request": NumberLong(0),
   "total_share": NumberLong(0),
   "ip": "NR",
   "men": NumberLong(0),
   "women": NumberLong(0),
   "user_agent": "NR",
   "players_desktop": NumberLong(0),
   "players_mobile": NumberLong(0),
   "players_tablet": NumberLong(0),
   "players_iframe": NumberLong(0),
   "13_17": NumberLong(0),
   "18_24": NumberLong(0),
   "25_34": NumberLong(0),
   "35_44": NumberLong(0),
   "45_54": NumberLong(0),
   "55_64": NumberLong(0),
   "65_plus": NumberLong(0),
   "first_name": "yyyy",
   "last_name": "xxxx",
   "email": "mail@gmx.fr",
   "phone": "NR",
   "zipcode": "3497409",
   "country": "NR",
   "birthday": "NR",
   "city": "fgromagne",
   "address": "NR",
   "state": "NR",
   "optin": NumberLong(0),
   "optin_partner": NumberLong(0),
   "custom_field_1": "Guitares",
   "custom_field_2": "NR",
   "custom_field_3": "NR",
   "univers": NumberLong(1) 
}
```

Here is an exemple of  1 index for 1 field:

[image]

And here another exemple 1index for many fields:

[image]

I use MongoDB with AWS EC2 Instances.
Thank you

Comment: See the part of the MongoDB manual regarding indexing strategies: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/indexes/

Comment: Not a new initiate here but perhaps it has never been said before. 1. StackOverflow is a "coding" questions site. Where is your code? 2. No idea what your document looks like or what your query patterns are. How can we answer? This never stops at least 10 people hunting reputation benefits from answering. But IMHO "this is not the JavaScript tag" ( where seemingly anything goes), so better your efforts in describing your problem.

Comment: Even though this is really a DBA question it is still too little information to be passed onto their site, you need to add more details